# Explicit type casting to byte overflows

Tags: java, casting, type-narrowing

```
public class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Explicit Type Conversion
        long t = 70;
        t= (byte) t * 2;
        System.out.println("Manual conversion"+t);
    }
}
```

Output :- Manual Conversion 140

Here am getting the output 140, but why? Because as byte ranges from -128 to 127 so why am getting 140, as its more than 127, it's exceeding!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you rewrite your question with properly formatted code, including a class name? Use the preview to see how we'll see your question, and imagine you were looking a post - ask yourself how you'd want it to look, and make sure the post looks that way. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more help on editing posts.

Comment: The multiplication has higher precedence than the cast, so it happens first, and then you cast the result (140) to `byte`. Use extra braces to avoid this: `((byte) t) * 2`. Either way, you assign the result to a `long`, so everything just needs to fit a `long`, not a `byte`, and `long` does not overflow at 140.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine the expression `t=(byte)t*2`. You have a `byte` (since you explicitly cast it) multiplied by an `int` (literal). The left operand is promoted to an `int` in order to perform the multiplication, so `140` is a valid value there. It is then promoted to a `long` and assigned back to `t`.

Answer (score 1):

Cast has higher operator precedence than multiplication. Use

```
t=(byte)(t*2)
```